# Why Matlab Coder is slow?

Tags: matlab, matlab-coder

I'm trying to build a Mex function in Matlab-r2015a using Matlab Coder. The entry point function I want to convert is `alg.m` which is called by `main.m`.

Following the procedure, I'm at the step in which I'm asked to "define the type of each input for every entry point function". I choose the automatic procedure and enter `main.m`

My problem is: in order to define the type of each input, the Matlab Coder takes a very long time; the same problem appears at the next step, when I have to check whether there are issues in the Matlab code. Is that because Matlab has to execute the whole `main.m+alg.m`?

I suspect this should be the case because when I impose values of parameters that make the computation faster, the input types and issue checks are done immediately. Anyway, I would like to have some more explanations and, if any, suggestions to solve the problem.

Comment: How can we reproduce your problem?

Comment: I would like to know how matlab coder works: does it need to run the matlab algorithm to create the mex function? Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, both steps `Define Input Types` and `Check for Run-Time Issues` run `main.m` which will in turn run `alg.m`.

If the input data types for the entry-point function don’t change, two test-benches (namely two versions of your `main.m`) can be written – a shorter one that invokes the entry-point once for defining input types, and a more comprehensive one that thoroughly exercises `alg.m`. The former can be used to quickly define input types, and the latter should be used when checking for run-time issues.